# DotNetNuke (DNN) How to import files and folders to a portal

Tags: database, file, import, dotnetnuke, directory

I have a plain html project that needs to be transferred to DotNetNuke.
This project is rather big and references nearly 3000 images that are located in a specific folder structure.
By now I removed header and footer from the html files and used these parts to create a skin as the main template. I also created the complete page structure in DotNetNuke.

Now I want to copy/paste the remaining content of each html file into an html-editor on the corresponding page in DotNetNuke. As a combination of skin and individual content the pages will look like in the previous html files.

**The question is** how do I get the image files transferred to DotNetNuke? Surely I could copy them into the appropriate Portal folder (and replace the path within the html code in the html-editors) but the image files then could not be managed in the asset manager that is part of the html editor as this requires to have the files added into the database (within the files and folders tables). So **is there any automated import option to get the files and folder structure into the database**. It really would help a lot and I do appreciate any kind of suggestion on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the files into the folders without using the File Manager interface.  Once copied, go to the File Manager (Asset Manager) and perform a File Sync.  Choose "Sync this folder and Subfolders".  That will automatically create the DB entries for you.

[image: DNN File Manager Sync Files]

Comment: There couldn't have been a better answer. It's that easy – if you know about it. I really hoped there's a way like this. Thank you very much.